# Atomically change attributes of a file

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I want to atomically change some attributes of a file. (Background: This is for a userspace NFS implementation where the SETATTR call sets several attributes on a file).

The problem I fail to solve is to make the update in an atomic way. That is, a different process that `stat()`s or `rename()`s the file should not see partially updated attributes.

Different simplified (i.e. no error checking and symlink handling) approaches with their downsides are:

- using traditional functions:

  ```
  int setattr(char *path, attributes attrs)
  {
      lchown(path, attr.owner, attr.group);
      chmod(path, attr.mode)
      utime(path, ...)
      return 0
  }
  ```

  This is not atomic (and fails to work properly on symlinks).
- using `fchown()` et al.

  ```
  int setattr(char *path, attributes attrs)
  {
       int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY);
       fchown(fd, attr.owner, attr.group);
       fchmod(fd, attr.mode);
       futimens(fd, ...);
       return 0;
  }
  ```

  This is somewhat atomic, but fails if the file's mode doesn't allow opening, or the file is a symlink (in which case the symlink's attributes should be modified instead of the target's). Adding `O_PATH` to the `open()` call doesn't help here either, as `fchown()` and `fchmod()` then fail.
- using `fchownat()` et al.

  ```
  int setattr(char *path, attributes attrs)
  {
       int fd = open(dirname(path), O_WRONLY | O_PATH);
       fchownat(fd, basename(path), attr.owner, attr.group, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);
       fchmodat(fd, basename(path), attr.mode, 0);
       utimensat(fd, basename(path), ..., AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);
       return 0;
  }
  ```

  This looks most promising, but again this isn't atomic.

Am I missing something or isn't there an approach that does what I want?

Comment: Doesn't `O_WRONLY` wipe out the file's contents?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It doesn't. That's the semantic of `O_TRUNC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible without writing your own custom syscall or kernel module for it.

While the Linux kernel itself definitely has the ability to make this happen, it doesn't expose any userspace API for it. This task would require either a single syscall that sets all the attributes at once, or some kind of "locking" mechanism to prevent files from being accessed (that is, `open`/`stat`) by other processes even if they have the rights to do so. Since Linux does not provide such a syscall, nor such a "locking" mechanism, what you want to achieve is not possible from userspace.

Comment: As said in a comment to @goswin-von-brederlow I think this is true. I now went with the `fchownat()` approach and as the daemon is single threaded races at least don't happen via NFS now which is the best I can achieve without kernel patching. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> That is, a different process that `stat()`s or `rename()`s the file should not see partially updated attributes.

If the file already exists there is little you can do to stop another process from accessing it before you modify it. That ship has sailed.

---

[`rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) is atomic.

The standard solution has been:

1. Create a file with a unique temporary name in the destination directory. It must be in the same directory to make sure it is in the filesystem/same-mount point, so that no file content (inode) copy is required.
2. Populate the file. If the file is written using buffered I/O (anything else than `write`, `pwrite`, `writev` or other *syscalls*) it needs to be flushed or closed (which causes a flush, which ends up doing one of the above syscalls).
3. Set correct permissions and attributes, if necessary. The permissions can be set when creating the file.
4. `rename` the file to its final filename. `rename` essentially atomically creates a new filename (hardlink) to the file content (inode) and removes the old filename.

This way when the file exists it is complete and has correct permissions and attributes.

Comment: If anything this would only add more problems since a program could create a file with the old name in the middle of the proces.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Nothing prevents that program to re-create the file when it already exits. `fopen(filename, "w")` and your file is gone.

Comment: And destroy the content of the file? Imagine if a command line tool did that to one of your programs. As I said, that just seems like adding more problems.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Reworded the solution to be less ambiguous for you.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli _Imagine if a command line tool did that to one of your programs_ - all of them do when you specify the same filename. Start with shell redirection `>file`.

Comment: Your answer is clear, what I meant is that you're basically solving a concurrency problem introducing another concurrency problem. Doesn't seem like an improvement, but that's probably opinion based at this point.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I agree, my original 1st sentence wasn't a viable solution, thanks for calling me out.

Comment: Darwin-based systems (MacOS, iOS) (and maybe some others by now) have an atomic `exchangedata()` function that atomically swaps file system entries for two files, making @MaximEgorushkin's suggestion fully atomic.

Comment: @Caleb The solution is atomic as long as the temporary file and the destination file reside in the same mount point. Do you mean _fully atomic_ even when the temporary file is created in another mount point?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I wrote the comment above from memory, but just checked the man page for `exchangedata()` and it looks like that function is deprecated starting with MacOS X 10.13. So... never mind? But to your question, my impression from the man page is that the operation is fully atomic as long as the files to be swapped exist in a file system that supports it, i.e. HFS+ or AFP.

Comment: I think `rename()` doesn't help me here as this would change the inode number which in turn has the potential to confuse nfs clients.

Comment: @UweKleine-König Rename doesn't change inode number. It rather creates a new hardlink.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and none of the examples you've shown is atomic. There is always a chance some other thread accesses the file between the chown and chmod or chmod and utimes call.

Under Linux there is the concept of a filesystem handle (as opposed to a file descriptor) for such cases as a userspace NFS server. Only thing I can find in google at the moment is the manpage from xfsprogs: [handle manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/handle.3.html). But I think this has been generalized in Linux in recent years to work with more filesystems.

Comment: What I did now is to ensure that at least nfs client usage is serialized and so have the updates atomic there. There is still a race with changes done to the local file system, but I can (and have to) live with that.

Comment: In that case no matter what you do it will just always work.There simply can't be any stat() or rename() going on because the serialization blocks them before the current action has completed. So the question has become pointless.

Comment: that was the general idea that it always works ... :-)